# How to use glob pattern in workingDirectory in azure yaml pipeline task?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, glob, azure-pipelines-yaml

In one of the task in onebranch Azure pipelines, I am installing one package say abc. After installation the folder gets created named abc.some_version (like abc.1.0.1). But the installation of the package installs the latest package. So the folder name may get changed.
In next task I want to go to the folder inside above installed package /packages/abc.1.0.1/build to execute some command `abc.exe do_something`.

```
    - script: |
        nuget install abc
      displayName: Install abc
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src

    - script: |
        abc.exe do_something -o "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src"
      displayName: Create
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\packages\abc.1.0.1\build
```

I want to use glob pattern in workingDirectory parameter of script like $(Build.SourcesDirectory\src\packages\abc.*\build

So for future if any new package version comes, I dont have to change the yaml file again.
After using the '*' in the workingDirectory path, I found that azure pipeline is taking * as a part of path itself.

Is there any way I can match the pattern inside workingDirectory or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can't. Glob patterns are, by definition, for matching *mulitple* things. You can't have multiple working directories.

Comment: Then is there any way I can cd to that package path without hardcoding the version number in the yml?

Answer (score 0):

Glob pattern is not supported when defining in

> workingDirectory:
> $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\packages\abc.1.0.1\build

You must hard code in the above scenario.

Glob pattern will work well in command line task Try command line to "cd" to the path.

[image]

```
cd C:\test\*\1
```

[image]